# Set characters size with ESC/POS (Java)

Tags: java, epson, escpos

I developed a small library in Java to send commands to a Epson TM-T70II printer with ESC/POS protocol.
I'm able to print all what I need but I can't find a way to change the font size of the text to a smaller value than the default font size.
Just to puntualize, "GS!" is not a ESC/POS useful command because it can only increase the font size, [see here to more info](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=34).

I was looking at ["ESC&"](https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=42) but I'm not sure this can be useful to reduce the font size.
Can you give me some suggestion and a small example of the command to use?

Comment: "ESC&" would be `"\u001b&"` but only found https://reference.epson-biz.com/modules/ref_escpos/index.php?content_id=72 which does not seem to fit your needs

Comment: That command should permit to define custom characters.

Answer (score 3):

TM-T70II has two types of Font, FontA(12x24) and FontB(9x17).
To change the font size, you can use the "ESC !" command

- Font A: "ESC ! 0" (1Bh 21h 00h)
- Font B: "ESC ! 1" (1Bh 21h 01h)

If it does not work you can send the "ESC @" first to clean the command buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

normalSize = {0x1B, 0x21, 0x03}

bold = {0x1B, 0x21, 0x08}

boldMedium = {0x1B, 0x21, 0x20}

boldLarge = {0x1B, 0x21, 0x10}